# How to collapse a submenu when another parent menu item is clicked with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Just wanted to pick your brains a bit with this problem I'm having setting up a collapsible menu using jquery.  I'm currently using the slideToggle() function to animate the collasping with a menu click, it works for closing and opening submenus independently.  But I'm trying to figure out a way to have the submenus collapse when another opens.  Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated.

**Jquery**

```
<script>
     function initMenu() {
       $('#menu ul').hide(); 
       $('#menu li a').click(

       function() {
         $(this).next().slideToggle('normal')

       });

     }
     $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">

     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">In the news</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

        </ul>
     </li>

     <li><a href="#">Who's Who?</a>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tackle Hunger Tackle  Hunger</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>

 </ul>
```

Thanks,

Andre

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/Gtbeh/1/)

```
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide(); 
    $('#menu > li > a').on('click', function() {
        $('#menu ul').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    });
}
$(document).ready(initMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li a').click(

    function() {
       $('#menu ul').hide('normal');
       $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');

});

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ex2z5/

Answer (score 0):

Put a class to your menu items i.e 'main-menu' and another to your submenu items i.e 'submenu' and make a function to close all the 'submenu' items when a click occurs on the 'main-menu' items.