# How to collapse a submenu when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to JS and I can't figure out how to close a submenu when clicked again (or if anything else is clicked, like the button which makes the menu appear.

[With this thread here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919579/how-to-collapse-a-submenu-when-another-parent-menu-item-is-clicked-with-jquery) I managed to open the submenu on click on the parent, but how can i close it again by click it again? Other threads that I found by google didn't help me at all...

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">

 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">In the news</a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    </ul>
 </li>

 <li><a href="#">Who's Who?</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Tackle Hunger Tackle  Hunger</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
 <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
    function initMenu() {
$('#menu ul').hide();
$('#menu li a').click(

function() {
    $('#menu ul').hide('normal');
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');

});
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();
});
```

When I click it again, it closes and then opens up again... Really thanks a lot for helping me with this problem!

[Here is also the jsfiddle of the other thread](http://jsfiddle.net/ex2z5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an `if` and check if the next element is hidden. 
Without the `if`, you will trigger hide and show twice by clicking on the same element.

```js
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        $('#menu ul').hide('normal');
        // check if the next element is hidden
        if($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">In the news</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

        </ul>
     </li>

     <li><a href="#">Who's Who?</a>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Tackle Hunger Tackle  Hunger</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine and saved me A LOT of time figuring it out by myself :)